# Imported system.web, I don't see server.mapPath?

Tags: c#, asp.net, server.mappath

I imported system.web into my class lib project.

Trying to find:

system.web.httpserverutility.server.mappath

But I dont' get the method in intellisense?

It is a .net 2.0 build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method is accessible via the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server object. Just set a reference to System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server and call the method like normal.

```
var server = HttpContext.Current.Server;
server.MapPath(SOME_VIRTUAL_PATH);
```

Answer (score 8):

`MapPath` is an instance method; you can only call it on an *instance* of `HttpServerUtility`.
If you know that your code will only be called during an HTTP request, you can call `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`.

Otherwise, call [`VitualPathUtility.ToAbsolute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150160.aspx).